# Cloning a github repository with .gitignore

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, gitignore

I have a public repository with my `index.js` file in `.gitignore`. I want to clone this for use in AWS EC2 using the command line. The problem is: the `index.js` file doesn't get cloned over, so the app doesn't work. How do I get around this problem without having to get rid of my `.gitignore`?

Comment: Why is index.js in gitignore?

Answer (score 2):

You can check in your `index.js` from the command line with the `-f` option:

```
git add -f index.js
```

That'll stage the file and you can then commit. The `-f` ignores the entry in `.gitignore`.